# Microsoft Edge flip card issue

Tags: css, html, microsoft-edge

when I am hovering on the card the card flips and it's absolutely fine in the Chrome browser. but in Microsoft Edge, the image is also visible and it's flipping.
[image: On Flip]

[image: On hover, the backside of the image in Microsoft Edge Browser]

```css
.main{
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  border: 1px solid red;

  padding:30px;
}

.first{
    display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  // justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  img{
    width:200px;
    border-radius:50%;
    margin-top: -50px;
  }
}
.second{
  color:blue;
}


//Need to provide override height and width of flip__card class
.flip__card {

  position: relative;

  &:hover &-front {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  }

  &:hover &-back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }

  &-front {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 300ms;
    transition: -webkit-transform 300ms;
    transition: transform 300ms;
    transition: transform 300ms, -webkit-transform 300ms;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);

  }

  &-back {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 300ms;
    transition: -webkit-transform 300ms;
    transition: transform 300ms;
    transition: transform 300ms, -webkit-transform 300ms;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main flip__card">
  <div class="first flip__card-front">
    <div><img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/221471/pexels-photo-221471.jpeg" width="200px" height="200px">
  </div>
    <div>
      Dummy text
    </div>
    <div>
    
  <div class="second flip__card-back">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quidem voluptatem mollitia eius veniam consectetur? Necessitatibus cumque obcaecati, laboriosam minima doloremque quod odit! Quo cupiditate dolorum explicabo laborum, iste tenetur rem.
  </div>
  
</div>
```

So while hovering on the card, in ME browser image is also visible and it's in a flip in position. whereas i am not using any image in the backside of the card.

Comment: If you use a code snippet, make sure it works, convert your SCSS to regular CSS to that effect in order for more people to help.

Comment: please check the link: https://codepen.io/wasifahmed/pen/MLVNKO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested on Microsoft Edge and it works. I think your error is due to simple HTML mistakes. Make sure all your `div` tags are closed correctly and at the right place, I don't think you want `.card-back` to be placed in `.card-front`.

```css
.main{
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding:30px;
}

.first{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}

.first img {
  width:200px;
  border-radius:50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
}

.second{
  color:blue;
}

.flip__card {
  position: relative;
}

.flip__card:hover .flip__card-front {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.flip__card:hover .flip__card-back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.flip__card-front {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 300ms;
  transition: -webkit-transform 300ms;
  transition: transform 300ms;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);

}

.flip__card-back {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 300ms;
  transition: -webkit-transform 300ms;
  transition: transform 300ms;
  transition: transform 300ms, -webkit-transform 300ms;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="main flip__card">

  <div class="first flip__card-front">
    <div><img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/221471/pexels-photo-221471.jpeg" width="200px" height="200px"></div>
    <div>Dummy text</div>
  </div>
   
  <div class="second flip__card-back">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quidem voluptatem mollitia eius veniam consectetur? Necessitatibus cumque obcaecati, laboriosam minima doloremque quod odit! Quo cupiditate dolorum explicabo laborum, iste tenetur rem.
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: No, its not working on ME browser. I have checked all my html(all the divs) and scss, i am assuming its the problem with ME browser only.

Comment: As I said, you have an unclosed div, Here is your [updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YBvyWY) and a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fwuh28jb/) as well to test it out on IE11. Both are working fine for me on both IE11 and Edge.

Comment: @wasif, I try to test the code suggested by Jake which is working with MS Edge. Can you please inform the current status of your issue? If your issue is still exist than we will try to provide further suggestions. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Wasif Is your problem fixed ? Was my answer the solution to your problem ? If so mark it as accepted please.